# Throwing exceptions from within CompletableFuture exceptionally clause

Tags: java

I am having a problem dealing with exceptions throw from CompletableFuture methods. I thought it should be possible to throw an exception from within the exceptionally clause of a CompletableFuture. For example, in the method below, I expected that `executeWork` would throw a RuntimeException because I am throwing one in the various `exceptionally` clauses, however, this does not work and I'm not sure why.

```
public void executeWork() {

  service.getAllWork().thenAccept(workList -> {
    for (String work: workList) {
      service.getWorkDetails(work)
        .thenAccept(a -> sendMessagetoQueue(work, a))
        .exceptionally(t -> {
          throw new RuntimeException("Error occurred looking up work details");
        });
    }
  }).exceptionally(t -> {
    throw new RuntimeException("Error occurred retrieving work list");
  });
}
```

Comment: By definition, a CompletableFuture (and more generally, Future) performs its task asynchronously, and the result, whether a value or an exception, is seen only when you request the end result of the asynchronous task.

Answer (score 4):

You're doing a few things wrong here ([async programming is hard](https://www.foreach.be/blog/parallel-and-asynchronous-programming-in-java-8)):

First, as @VGR noted, `executeWork()` will not throw an exception when things go bad - because all the actual work is done on another thread. `executeWork()` will actually return immediately - after scheduling all the work but without completing any of it. You can call `get()` on the last `CompletableFuture`, which will then wait for the work completion, or failure, and will throw any relevant exceptions. But that is force-syncing and considered an anti-pattern.

Secondly, you don't need to `throw new RuntimeException()` from the `exceptionally()` handle - that one is actually called with the correct error (`t`) in your case.

looking at an analogous synchronous code, your sample looks something like this:

```
try {
  for (String work : service.getAllWork()) {
    try {
      var a = service.getWorkDetails(work);
      sendMessageToQueue(work, a);
    } catch (SomeException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Error occurred looking up work details");
    }
  }
} catch (SomeOtherException e) {
  throw new RuntimeException("Error occured retrieving work list");
}
```

So as you can see, there's no benefit from catching the exceptions and throwing `RuntimeException` (which also hides the real error) instead of just letting the exceptions propagate to where you can handle them.

The purpose of an `exceptionally()` step is to *recover from exceptions* - such as putting default values when retrieving data from user or IO has failed, or similar things. Example:

```
service.getAllWork().thenApply(workList -> workList.stream()
    .map(work -> service.getWorkDetails(work)
        .thenAccept(a -> sendMessageToQueue(work, a)
        .exceptionally(e -> {
          reportWorkFailureToQueue(work, e);
          return null;
        })
     )
).thenCompose(futStream -> 
    CompletableFuture.allOf(futStream.toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new)))
.exceptionlly(e -> {
   // handle getAllWork() failures here, getWorkDetail/sendMessageToQueue
   // failures were resolved by the previous exceptionally and converted to null values
});
```